# Lucky Bamboo stem sags but seems healthy, how do I fix this?

Tags: plant-health, support, lucky-bamboo

I've had this Lucky Bamboo plant for almost 4 years. It has got two shoots coming out of the main stem, the longer of which is now unable to support itself.

We had a very dry winter and I had a hard time with a lot of my plants; it got really bad when I had to go away for a week. I came back and my bamboo was yellowing and the branch bent over and sagging. This bamboo seems to be healthy now, but that large shoot continues to sag.

Its been this way for a couple months now. I have to keep it next to something to support the shoot. I can tell that if I support the base of the shoot (about an inch above the main stem) with my fingers, the whole shoot stands up fine - so I guess it's the base of the shoot that is the problem.

Is there a way to get the shoot to support its own weight? Or is there some thing I should put in the shoot to help it do so?

Comment: Any chance of a picture of the plant, also showing the container its growing in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds to me like your bamboo isn't getting enough light, and because of that the stems are not growing stout enough to support themselves after they get to a certain height.  You likely need to increase the light you are giving the plant, and if the larger stem won't support itself, you can always cut it off near the base and root it into a new plant.